# When does an infinite series have a zero?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, decidability

Given an infinite series:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n} x^n$$

And assume analytic continuation.

Is there any algorithm that will tell us if there is a solution to $f(x)=0$ where $x$ is real, just knowing some procedure for generating the coefficients $a_n$? Or perhaps this is an undecidable problem?

Comment: Assume the series is finite. That is, a polynomial in $x$. You can ask the same question.

Comment: As a somewhat cheeky first crack: if $a_0 = 0$ then the answer is yes!

Comment: Decision will depend on the specific sequence.

Comment: Note that the Taylor series for $\sin x$ has infinitely many zeroes, while the one for $e^x$ has none.

Comment: Indeed, as @MPW suggests, how do we know that the series for sine gives a function with a zero? My proof involves knowing the differential equation that the sine satisfies, and working from there. Very special information, therefore.